# KMS Decryption result is not getting assigned to Abstract class static variable

Tags: node.js, abstract, amazon-kms

We are encrypting our environment variable "dbPassword" in AWS lambda function and we are trying to decrypt that encrypted value in our typescript file.

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const kmsClient = new AWS.KMS({region: 'us-east-1'});

class EncryptionUtility
{
    static async decryptEnvironmentVariable(encryptedValue: string): string {
        try
        {
            console.log("function decryptEnvironmentVariable() input value => ",encryptedValue);
            
            const req = {
                CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(encryptedValue, 'base64'),
                EncryptionContext: { LambdaFunctionName: 'ioh_reference_data_service' },
            };
            
            const decryptResult = await kmsClient.decrypt(req).promise();
           
            if (Buffer.isBuffer(decryptResult.Plaintext)) {
                return Buffer.from(decryptResult.Plaintext).toString();
            } 
            else 
            {
                throw new Error('We have a problem');
            }
            
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            console.log("Exception Generated while executing decryptEnvironmentVariable() => ",e);
        }
    }
}


export abstract class Config {
   
    static dbPassword: string = await EncryptionUtility.decryptEnvironmentVariable(process.env.dbPassword);
 
}
```

In above code, I want my **dbPassword** static variable of **Config** class should have decrypted value.

When I am printing **Config.dbPassword** in console I am getting **undefined**.

Also, I am getting error that await cannot be used in abstract class.

Config class is being used at many other places, and I want to have decrypted value in me Config class itself so that other places will be intact.

Can you please provide me the solution like how can I achieve this decrypted value in my Config static variables?

Anyone leads would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is that you can't use await in the class field initialization, especially in a static context. Instead, you can set dbPassword in a separate static method or during the Lambda initialization.

You need to do something similar to this:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const kmsClient = new AWS.KMS({ region: 'us-east-1' });

class EncryptionUtility {
  static async decryptEnvironmentVariable(encryptedValue: string): Promise<string> {
    try {
      console.log("function decryptEnvironmentVariable() input value => ", encryptedValue);

      const req = {
        CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(encryptedValue, 'base64'),
        EncryptionContext: { LambdaFunctionName: 'ioh_reference_data_service' },
      };

      const decryptResult = await kmsClient.decrypt(req).promise();

      if (Buffer.isBuffer(decryptResult.Plaintext)) {
        return Buffer.from(decryptResult.Plaintext).toString();
      } else {
        throw new Error('We have a problem');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Exception Generated while executing decryptEnvironmentVariable() => ", e);
      throw e; 
    }
  }
}

export abstract class Config {
  static dbPassword: string;

  static async initializeConfig() {
    try {
      Config.dbPassword = await EncryptionUtility.decryptEnvironmentVariable(process.env.dbPassword);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error initializing Config:", e);
    }
  }
}

Config.initializeConfig();
```

However, instead of using encrypted environment variables, why not use ParameterStore. It would simplify things greatly.